# svn 2 projects same engine - joomla

Tags: svn, joomla

Currently I have to repositories for two joomla components:

/var/svn/component1
*structure root*
administrator/components/com_component1
components/com_component1

/var/svn/component2
*structure root*
administrator/components/com_component2
components/com_component2

The problem is most of the code is similar e.g component1 have extra reviews added but "engine" is the same

Now i would like to make changes to engine or fix bug I have do it twice?

How to organize svn server to have 1 engine (component base) and extras in Joomla environment? structure of directories has to be the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVN externals.  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: tortiose svn allows editing of externals.  Please read the documentation.